# Why does Node have no getElementByTagName()?

Tags: java, xml, parsing, dom

I would like to understand why I have to do the following when I want to access a specific element value during XML parsing:

```
    NodeList controlList = poDoc.getElementsByTagName("control");
    Node controlNode = controlList.item(0); 
    Element controlElem = (Element) controlNode;

    usageType = controlElem.getElementsByTagName("usage_type").item(0).getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
```

Here I have to cast the controlNode to (Element), only because I want to access another element deeper down the DOM tree. This is all working as expected, I just would like to understand why this is the way it is. Why can't there be a getElementByTagName or similar call for the Node-object? Or is there and I just don't know it. Since I'm quite new to Java, this might be the case. There surely is a better reason to this than "because that's the way the interface was implemented".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only documents and elements can contain elements.

So the designers of the DOM API simpy *decided* to define the method 
`getElementsByTagName` only in the `Node` classes `Document` and `Element`.

An *alternative* design would have been to define `getElementsByTagName` in the `Node` class and return an empty node list if the node cannot contain elements. (This is roughly the design decision made by the XPath spec).

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Accepted answer for the XPath-reference.

Answer (score 1):

According to the javadoc, [`Node`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html) is any piece of data that can exist in an XML doc, including comments, headers, and text (text value of XML element) so not all kind of nodes can have have a "name" or have child elements.

an [`Element`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Element.html) defines the kinds of node that may have child elements that may be retrieved by a name.

Answer (score 1):

By XML standards, every entity in an XML document is a `Node`, and not everything in an XML document can have child elements. The parser can't know if a referenced `Node` is a header, an element, or even a comment, so it would be unwise to have such a method without first checking its type.

Even if you expect your XML to be formatted a certain way, it's typical to check if a `Node` is actually an `Element`, for example:

```
if(node instanceof Element) {
    NodeList usagetypes = ((Element)node).getElementsByTagName("usage_types");
    ...
```